# With DotNet (Core/Standrad) how do I the project version at build time?

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines, dotnetcorecli

I'm able to set the project version by adding the  tag to the .csproj file,
but I'd like to change that value programatically inside the pipeline.

I hacked together a script to do accomplish that, but it feels sloppy.

That's got to be a way to do this through the CLI, but I'm just not finding it.

Is there a command similar to this that I'm overlooking?

```sh
dotnet build -project-version 1.2.3
```

If no command exists, what have you done to set the project build version in your pipelines?

Comment: All the answers were quite helpful. If you have another way to solve this, please add it. I still wish Azure Pipelines just had a "semver" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use the following in my pipeline.

```
dotnet build -p:VersionPrefix="$(buildNumber)" -p:VersionSuffix="$(buildPipline)"
```

and in my csproj file i have

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.1</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix>local</VersionSuffix>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to get the version number in code, i use the following

```
public static string Version => System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion;
```

if you're using azure pipelines, you can add a powershell script, which declares the version based on the date & time.

```
 Write-Host "Generating Build Number"
$baseDate = [datetime]"01/01/2019"
$currentDate = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Eastern Standard Time')
$interval = NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $baseDate –End $currentDate
$days = $interval.Days
$hour = $currentDate.ToString("HH")
$minute = $currentDate.ToString("mm")

$version = "1.0.$days.$hour$minute"
$version_npm = "1.$days.$($currentDate.ToString("Hmm"))"
if($currentDate.ToString("HH") -eq "00")
{
    $version_npm = "1.$days.25$($currentDate.ToString("mm"))"
}
Write-Host "Version: $version"
Write-Host "npm Version: $version_npm"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildNumber]$version"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildNumber_npm]$version_npm"
```

Comment: Your answer was pretty close to what I was looking for.
I hadn't run into the "-p" parameter for "dotnet build" (or dotnet pack, etc.)
In addition to the VersionPrefix and VersionSuffix, it looks like you can just do this:

"dotnet build -p:Version=5.6.7"

As for determining which version to set, I'm just storing a text file in the repo itself and auto-incrementing the last digit automatically when the master branch builds.

I do wish that Azure Pipelines just had a "Semver" command.
You're answer was quite helpful and makes my pipeline a little less hacky.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Assembly Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task) extension, which can update project `AssemblyInfo` files and .Net Core / .Net Standard project files `.csproj`. For detailed instructions on how to configure the extension please see the following link:

https://github.com/BMuuN/vsts-assemblyinfo-task/wiki/Versioning

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way to do this is using environment variables in the .csproj file like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(APPVERSION)' != ''">
    <InformationalVersion>$(APPVERSION)</InformationalVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And then set the environment variables in your build server.